# How dangerous is it to use BEGIN TRANSACTION in Management Studio?

Tags: t-sql, transactions

When modifying data in immediate mode in t-sql, I will wrap my changes in BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT|ROLLBACK for safety's sake. However, I have recently become concerned about the impact of failing to issue the COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

I commonly leave my SSMS window open from day-to-day as I am developing code and may wish to review or reuse some piece of sql. Is there a safe way to do this? If I close the window I know all uncommitted transactions get resolved. But what if I don't close it? What if, for example, I'm told to urgently make a change in a production table. If I don't commit that, clearly there will be an impact on our users.

How can I be certain this is not the case? When I execute a COMMIT and I see the message "The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION" -- what is the scope of that message? Does it mean there are none in the default database for that pane or none in any available database? And if I run

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1
```

and get no results, what does it mean if I then execute a COMMIT and see it run with no response (i.e., there WAS an uncommitted transaction.)

Put simply, what is the scope of the COMMIT and how do I affect that?

Answer (score 0):

It's no more dangerous to use transactions in deployed code. Each way there are chances that you'll do or create something that could leave a transaction open. So, there are steps to take in each case to protect against it.

When you issue a "commit tran" it will only try to commit a tran within your connection. It does not go outside of your connection to find trans to commit. The scope is local to your connection.

Just run "select @@trancount" from any window you are working in before you are done. @@TRANCOUNT stores the number of transactions open in the current connection.

I always separate my work from purely select/read only/research type work with one instance of SSMS and if I need to modify any data in place I open a separate SSMS. Only when needed and shut it down when Im done.

You cannot affect the scope of a "commit" command (that I know of).

Comment: In Management Studio, I can open many "New Query" windows & sometimes have a dozen of them open and left open for days. Each window defaults to the database shown in the "Available Databases" above. Say I INSERT to a table in the default database db1 inside of a START TRAN, but I never COMMIT. Then I go to any of the other open windows, select db1 as the default, and COMMIT. Will that close the transaction opened in the other window? I.e., when I do the COMMIT, does it need to be in the SAME WINDOW using the SAME DEFAULT DATABASE? That's what I meant by "scope" in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: The transaction is tied to the connection. So when you ask "need to be in the SAME WINDOW" I can answer Yes, but it's not about the window. It's the connection. That is the thing the the transaction is tied to. You can have connections without a query window and those connections may open a transaction (a stored proc executed in a job for example). So its the connection that the tran was opened in... that is where the tran must be closed; either committed or rollback.

Comment: One last thing to add, if you open a transaction while in one DB, then move to another DB with either the USE command or by selecting a new DB in SSMS, you're connection still owns the opened transaction. So, any commit/rollback will still work on that transaction. Your use of the "USE" command is ignored by the transaction since it's not a DML statement.A transaction is "owned" by a connection, not a connection and database.

Comment: Really. Thank you very much -- can you point me to actual documentation of what you wrote? I found it a bit confusing and was surprised to find so little on the subject with a google search. I figured it was obscure because no one really cared, which I found odd.